# Multidimension array in VB.net (ASP.net)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, multidimensional-array

How do I create a multidimension array in VB.net?  I want to specify the dimensions of the array in the code, but the array must be global.

```
Dim canvas()() As Integer
```

Then later on

```
x = someValue
y = someValue
canvas = New Integer(x)(y)
```

Cheers!

Comment: ()() is a jagged array... Oh I see(as the screen scrolls down) that you have caught that. (,) is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just worked it out

```
Dim canvas(,) As Integer
ReDim canvas(canvasWidth, canvasHeight)
```

Answer (score 2):

One thing to note, arrays are zero based.

```
Dim foo(,) As Byte
Dim img As New Bitmap(8, 8)
ReDim foo(img.Width - 1, img.Height - 1)
```